Cassette tape of science-fiction short stories with a blue cover with an astronaut
When I was a child my older brother had a cassette tape with some short sci-fi stories on. I think it must have been around 1992 to 1993 and the narrator was British. I've been searching for years because I remember being too young for some of them.
The cover was blue with a NASA astronaut on the front, but that doesn't narrow it down. What I remember of the stories:

A young boy gets kidnapped by his parents lab assistant who turns out to be an android. He is taken to a small moon where there are rat-like creatures that want him.
A story where these aliens that appear on earth resemble sea anemones, but are electric and kill the people that touch them.
A story where a guy is the last survivor of mankind and is living in his ship taking the fight to an alien race.
A story where Earth's oxygen is running out. The child in the family recalls playing outside with his friends and one of the other children collapses from an asthma attack. The child has a pet hamster that he can keep because it consumes little air, but recalls the neighbours having a dog that needs putting down because of how much oxygen it consumes.


Could this have been a follow-along to the audio while you read type of thing?

No, not that i remeber he was a alot older, it was a short story cassette tape, the narrator was british.

Can you recall if the stories were by one or multiple authors?

They were different authors i believe, the title was something generic like, amazing sci fi stories or along those lines.

This is SF on Tape released in the UK in 1993. It has a blue cover, an astronaut on the front, and a British narrator.

"Space Egg" by Anthony Masters is the story about the boy, the android, and the rat creatures.

"ZAP!" by Jan Dean is the story about the electric alien sea anemones.

"The Mars Ark" by Helen Dunmore is the story about oxygen running out on Earth.

"Graveyard Orbit" by Stephen Bowkett is the story about the last survivor of mankind on his spaceship.


You can listen to it on YouTube.

Image by H.M. Friendly

Thats it as soon as i read zap my brain opened up to a distant memory! Fantasic thank-you all for the detective work!

I am happy he found it for you @Jack87 You can click the tick at the top left of the answer so it becomes green to accept the answer as correct.

I was quite a fan of Helen Dunmore's "Burning Bright". But I never knew she'd written any sci-fi. I'll have to check Goodreads.
